# In mysql ORDER BY, is it possible to use CASE inside IF condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, sql-order-by

I have a SELECT query which have **ORDER BY**

What I want is

if(type=2 AND (station=0 OR station=1)) then

```
SELECT * FROM table
 ORDER BY CASE type
          WHEN 1 OR 2 THEN 1
          WHEN 3 THEN 2
          ELSE 4
    END,CAST(choice AS SIGNED ) DESC
```

if(type=2 AND station=2) then

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY CASE type
         WHEN 1 THEN 1
         WHEN 2 THEN 2
         WHEN 3 THEN 3
         ELSE 4   
   END,CAST(choice AS SIGNED ) DESC
```

> Is it possible to place CASE inside IF condition and how?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table
 ORDER BY IF(type=2 AND (station=0 OR station=1))
          {
          CASE type
           WHEN 1 OR 2 THEN 1
           WHEN 3 THEN 2
           ELSE 4
          END,CAST(choice AS SIGNED ) DESC
          }
          ELSEIF(type=2 AND station=2)
          {
          CASE type
           WHEN 1 THEN 1
           WHEN 2 THEN 2
           WHEN 3 THEN 3
           ELSE 4
          END,CAST(choice AS SIGNED ) DESC,
          }
```

Comment: Mysql doesn't support this form of if statement in a query

Comment: For all cases, type must be 2 (enforced by both IF and ELSEIF), so why are you (tying to) use a CASE on type? And what should the order be when type is *not* 2 or station is not 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: Can you add sample input data and expected output with enough records as an edit to your post?

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention, there was a case where **type!=2** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can nest case statement within if statement.

But you can nest case within case statement.

Try,

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN type=2 AND (station=0 OR station=1) 
               THEN 
               CASE type
                    WHEN 1 OR 2 THEN 1
                    WHEN 3 THEN 2
                    ELSE 4
                    END
               WHEN type=2 AND station=2 
               THEN 
               CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN 2 THEN 2
                    WHEN 3 THEN 3
                    ELSE 4   
               END
    END ,CAST(choice AS SIGNED ) DESC
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ejgoaqko)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the query and got the result as expected.